# Why is there a radioactivity sign on the Eurofighter's missile?

Tags: missiles, eurofighter-typhoon

In [this link](https://www.nationalfeiertag21.at/virtueller-rundgang.html?startscene=18) you see a Eurofighter Typhoon having a missile with a radioactivity sign on it. The inscription below "DANGER" is too small, I can't read it. This is an Austrian Eurofighter plane, so it can't be a nuke, can it?

Edit: I just figured out you can zoom in to read it. Sorry for asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Danger - Radio frequency decoy dispenser"

So not radioactive, but rather radio wavelength emissions.

Quite possibly similar to this:
https://www.baesystems.com/en/product/anale55-fiberoptic-towed-decoy

"AN/ALE-55 fiber-optic towed decoy"

Comment: Do you know why they are using the symbol for [ionizing radiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hazard_symbol#Ionizing_radiation_symbol), rather than [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Radio_waves_hazard_symbol.svg) for non-ionizing radiation warning?

Comment: @Bianfable: I've got two guesses: a) they don't know any better, b) they *do* know better, but are not sure everybody else does.

Comment: @JörgWMittag That's what I thought too, many people probably know the ionizing sign but not the other one.

Comment: The link is dead.

Comment: My link? Works just fine for me.